# jQuery UI switch focus on multiple modal dialogs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, focus, modal-dialog

is it possible to change focus between multiple jQuery UI modal dialogs?

Currently I open a few dialogs, positions relative and shifted to each other, so I can see them all. But when I click on any of the dialogs in the "background", they don't get focused. I have to close the dialogs in the reverse order that they have been opened by, so they gain focus one by one.

Yes, I know, the purpose of a modal dialog is to block everything else.
But can it block everything except other modal dialogs?

Btw. its not a must-have. I'm looking for a simple solution. If it requires a lot of changes to jquery ui core, its not worth the time

Comment: I don't think that would be possible in an easy way. I mean, in theory you would have to make some changes on the library related with click events, apply some css styles during the event and so on. I wouldnt try unless I would really need that. But, of course, I can be wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

Call the dialog instance's [moveToTop method (see Methods tab)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

FWIW, there is also a focus event (see Events tab on previous link) which may be helpful in knowing when to call the method.

Comment: thanks. nice idea, but i can't get it quite to work. i tried binding the .moveToTop method to the click event. the problem is that the other dialogs are inactive/disabled/or whatever dialog modality does to them, so they don't don't catch the click event if they are not active (already on top of stack)

Comment: moveToTop definitely doesn't work with modality. i'm trying to do a workaround. not exactly what i was looking for but good enough. make the dialogs draggable and delete the extra overlays (each modal dialog sets its own overlay). the problem is that the overlay is destroyed automatically with the button. so if you close the bottom dialog first, the overlay disappears. i'll have to extend the close event to move the single overlay manually on each close. unless someone has a better idea

Comment: I see. I do read that you mentioned modal, but I guess I didn't realize that's what you were dealing with. I do a lot of dialogs on a system I build, but the large majority of them are not modal. So moveToTop seemed natural to me.

Comment: thats ok, it was a good try. anyway, the workaround performs very well. i can post the code if you are interested